# In google colab's jupyter notebook, why can i call a function before defining it? Why is it not an error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image: It doesn't error]

When I enter the same code in a python IDE instead of the notebook it causes an error as expected.

Comment: I think it's because they just don't have that functionality build into Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Most likely, you already defined the function earlier, possibly in another cell, or in a previous run of some version of this cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that I could think of is you ran the cell earlier.
From how I understand Google Colab, if you run the cell it stores that function/ 'remembers it' so if you re-run the cell it won't give an error.

Same reason why running a cell that changes data can only work once.

But I might be wrong.

As long as your code works I wouldn't worry too much about it. You can always place the function in a new cell above the one where you call the function. I would mainly do this because it looks better.

Comment: I understand, I have run the cell earlier. I reset the runtime and it now shows an error as I expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That is not supposed to happen. Is it possible that you have already run a cell where `repeat_lyrics` was defined before actually calling it?

Try restarting the Jupyter runtime and see if you can still do it.

When you run a cell in Jupyter defining an object, you can use it across cells (provided it's in global scope), including cells that precede it.